# magento 2.2.4 white blank page after setup:di:compile on windows 10

Tags: magento2.2.4

I have installed `Magento 2.2.4`.

After installation, it was good, loading pages as expected.

But, when I **setup:di:compile**, it gives blank page on frontend and admin as well.

Once I delete generated folder and load page, it will again ok, and no blank page.

I checked it on Ubuntu, it works fine.

Comment: any error while run setup:di:compile or run successfully?

Comment: Have you check magento log files?

Comment: @Suresh Chikani: no error while running setup:di command

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya: i see no error in logs, but i will share my log here

Comment: Sometimes this happens because symlinks are not allowed in template settings: Advanced > Developer > Template Settings > Allow Symlinks

Answer (score 9):

I am also facing the same issue for me a temporary fix is force deploying developer mode (even if you are already on it or not) **i.e. Executing the following command after di compile**

```
 php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

It is a temporary / quick fix , i am still looking into issue will update answer if find the root cause

Comment: i am already in developer mode, but same issue in developer mode as well

Comment: what i am trying to say is after running compile command , again set mode to developer even though you are on it already

Comment: awesome! it works

Comment: What the hell... this worked for me

Answer (score 5):

First Open “Validator.php” file located as the following path.
vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

find the function :

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
```

Now inside this function find this line of code.

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

And replace this line of code with the below code.

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Now compile your Magento by using commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: This is really wonderful and works for me. Thank you very much to save my precious time.

Answer (score 2):

**I have fixed same issue on my Windows 10 system using below steps**

> 1) increase memory_limit = 3000M
>
> 2) new fresh installation Magento 2.1.8 with wamp server php v 7.0.32

Now admin and front both working fine, please let me know if its work for you.

Answer (score 0):

***Windows 10 Env Run deploy and compilation***

As per discussion, you are already in ***developer*** mode.

- Try to install ***git bash*** or you can use ***powershell***
  My choice is ***git bash***.
- Go to ***Magento*** Root directory.
  Need to give permission when you run:
  `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
  Try to give permission on,
  `chmod 777 -R generated/ var/ pub/static`
- Even you have to give permission after
  `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Comment: done but the issue is still the same i.e., fresh Magento 2.2.4 after di:compile shows blank white screen on the frontend and "not redirecting properly" on the backend.

Comment: Please check mod_rewrite is enable or not. if not enable it and try again.

Answer (score -1):

Please run following command :

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush