# Setup Magento 2.1.6 Successfully But when run admin URL shows Black screen

Tags: magento2

Please find below attached screenshot

[image: Magento 2.1.6]

Comment: please try: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224912/magento-2-2-4-white-blank-page-after-setupdicompile-on-windows-10 OR https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused due to the permission issue on the static files.

To fix this issue;

1) Open `app/etc/env.php` and set `'MAGE_MODE' => 'developer',`.

2) Go to file path `pub/static/`

3) Check whether .htaccess file is available (Press Ctrl+H to view the hidden file).

4) If not available, based on the Magento version, get .htaccess file in the file path `pub/static/` and copy into your file structure.

5) Finally, clear your browser and Magento cache and check it.
(optionally you can run the below command to clear Magento Cache)

> php bin/magento cache:flush

P.S: If you still encounter the same issue after trying above steps, copy files under `pub/static` to some other location in your PC and delete all files under `pub/static`. Clean Magento/Browser cache again and try back.

Comment: Try it but still get same error

Answer (score 0):

Go to your magento 2 installation directory through terminal and run these commands.

```
icacls "C:\PathToMagentoInstallationRoot\" /grant Users:F

icacls "C:\PathToMagentoInstallationRoot\pub\" /grant Users:F

icacls "C:\PathToMagentoInstallationRoot\generated\" /grant Users:F

icacls "C:\PathToMagentoInstallationRoot\var\*" /grant Users:F

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

del C:\PathToMagentoInstallationRoot\generated\*

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I have installing on windows machine. Could these commands run on windows also?

Comment: I have updated my answer according to windows. Please try this.

Comment: Starting 2 commands are working but i don't have generated folder so icacls "C:\PathToMagentoInstallationRoot\generated\" /grant Users:F not working

Comment: Okay, then manually create this folder in you magento directory and the run all these commands. and skip the second last command.

Comment: did it helped.?

Comment: Its not working for me now i have leave it and installed 2.2.7 version