# Magento 2.3.4 blank page error frontend

Tags: magento2.3, error, log, frontend-error

We face a issue with our Magento 2.3.4, we got a blank page error when we visit the frontend.

Already enabled `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` but still no error is displayed.

We got a debug.log file with the following errors:

```
[2020-03-17 10:33:01] main.INFO: Broken reference: the '' element cannot be added as child to '', because the latter doesn't exist [] []
```

I already tried to remove all cache etc, but I can not find and solve this issue.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: you remove this file pub/generated/metadata/global.php and run php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy the

Comment: @MohitPatel Thanks! I tried this, but that does not seems to work. But the issue is related to the compile.

Comment: i think this problem pls try this links :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252188/magento-2-2-7-admin-panel-blank-page

Comment: @MohitPatel Thanks! But we already run 2.3.4. for a while without a problem. This seems to be related to 2.3.3. Are you sure this edit is still necessary?

Comment: Please try this above link but i am noy sure but you are try . may be complete the issues.

Comment: @MohitPatel Thanks! I tried this, but it did not work, same issue.

Comment: you should start disabling third party modules there is a good chance the problem is being caused by a module. I also found a similar problem being caused by enabling the move js code to bottom of page option.

Comment: @paj Thanks! That's what I also thought, but that did not work. I disabled all modules and still faces the same issue. I can not really understand why Magento is not displaying any error to solve the issue.

Comment: try this awesome solution, it always works for me... https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318528

Answer (score 1):

Try to debug in this class and see what elements it is referencing and then find those in your XML files - vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/ScheduledStructure/Helper.php:184

Comment: Thanks! But how should we debug this and what should we change in this case?

Comment: Put a xdebug breakpoint if you already have that setup. If not then try doing error_log(); or do echo; die; for the values - $structure, $key, $type, $parentName . $alias

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> app/bootstrap.php

Replace `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` To `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Thanks! I already tried his, but still no error is displayed. I see that we face this error after compile. Any ideas?

Comment: any console error ? or try to view your page source maybe display error in page-source

Comment: No the console also does not display any error, also php error logs are empty.

Comment: What is your magento mode?

Comment: Running dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

try this awesome solution. it works for me...
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318528

in this solution, we need to change only one line in **"Validator.php"** file which is located at vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

find the function which named **"protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)"**

inside this function you will see following line...

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

you have to replace this line with below following line

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Original Answer you will see at : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/318528

**Post Credit :- Sushant Vishwas**